# How to make HandsOnTable comment read-only

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have

```
comments:true
```

in my HandsOnTable and I populate the comments for a cell manually.

Now, how can I make the comment read-only / non-editable ?

Comment: make the cell read only or the comment?

Comment: Want to make comment readonly

Comment: @ZekeDroid Thanks for pointing out, I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

Add the disabled attribute to the text area.

```
<textarea class="htCommentTextArea" disabled=""></textarea>
$(".htCommentTextArea").attr("disabled","disabled");
```